# Scraping MLB Gameday Data

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup to try and scrape data from the MLB gameday pages.

Right now, I'm simply trying to extract gameday ids.

Here's an example of a page:

```
url = "http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2017/month_04/day_20/epg.xml"

soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(d_url), "lxml")
```

After this, I'm not sure how to navigate and find the ids.

They're stored in a 2 different places for each game:

```
  game_data_directory="/components/game/mlb/year_2017/month_04/day_20/
                       gid_2017_04_20_bosmlb_tormlb_1"

gameday="2017_04_20_bosmlb_tormlb_1"
```

What's the best way to find, and then store the ids?

Thanks.

Comment: `'_'.join(game_data_directory.split('/')[-1].split('_')[1:])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = requests.get('http://gd2.mlb.com/components/game/mlb/year_2017/month_04/day_20/epg.xml')
data = BeautifulSoup(data.content, "lxml")

for game in data.find_all('game'):
    print(game['game_data_directory'])
    pos = game['game_data_directory'].rfind('/')
    print(game['game_data_directory'][46:])
```